Redirect to non-Wordpress version of home page for search results via index.php customization overwritten
Because the Wordpress pages in my web site can have an extremely unacceptable 2000+ millisecond TTFB, non-Wordpress web pages has been my approach. By saving large HTML blocks in a couple of additional database tables, page generation is streamlined, with TTFB figures typically some 124 - 200 milliseconds by way of bytecheck.com. My problem: getting search results which bring up my home page revert to the slow loading Wordpress version of my home page. This is because the customization of my index.php file which redirects to the faster loading non-Wordpress home page when the referrer does not contain "https://(domain) gets overwritten. When this file is customized, search results redirect to /page.php?home for my Home page with Google, Bing, etc. But, a couple of days later, I find this (domain name)/page.php?home is missing, and that irksome 2+ secon delay returns. I  want to stop this from being overwritten. I am ready to set the maximum execution time to 500 milliseconds--so that if this happens again, home page search results either bring up a promptly loading home page or nothing at all. A cache plugin could work, but some css/js content still comes right off my web server, instead of a CDN source. Furthermore, this complicates things a bit. Teh last time I tried a cache plugin, it messed things up, so I got rid of it.
Any ideas?

Either there's something misconfigured in your WP install or your hosting is completely inadequate to your traffic, there's no way you should be seeing a TTFB that high. I run my own site on WP and the TTFB without cache or CDN is under 400ms.
Could you share the contents of your homepage template (index.php/home/php/whatever)?
